# Find out how long and how long an axios request takes

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In my vue application, a fairly large number of axios requests are sent.
There are both light ones, which are performed in a fraction of a second, and heavy ones, which require more time to process. I want to make one loader component and control it in the interceptor, but I can somehow do it so that it is not activated for every request, but maybe by some flag in the requests

I tried with headers but failed

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `time()` and `timeEnd()`

```
console.time("Time of Axios request");
   // code for the Axios request goes here  
console.timeEnd("Time of Axios request");
```

The length of time it takes for the code to run in between the two methods will be printed in the console of your web browser. Note that the labels ("Time of Axios request") **must be identical** in both methods.